# Simple backup script

Tags: windows, batch-file, backup, robocopy

I used to maintain an in house cmd line tool for support techs. As such I wanted to make sure that I kept a archive of previous versions of the file in case something went sideways.

I wanted to create a simple batch file that I could run as a scheduled task every X days to make a copy of the development folder on a network share.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with. Not the most elegant, but it got the job done. I've gone through an anonymized the script but it wouldn't be hard to replace the directory paths to what suits your needs.

```
@echo off
rem Copies the targeted directory to a folder in my documents and appends the date.
rem It also copies it to a backup dir on the shared drive itself

rem This part uses the current date a time, but arranges it into a useful manner
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a%%b)


rem This copies the folder from the shared drive to a local copy in Documents.
robocopy "Z:\Support\Development" "C:\Users\SmithJ\Documents\Support_Tool\%mydate%" /LOG+:"C:\Users\SmithJ\Documents\Support_Tool\log.txt"

rem This copies the same shared folder to a backup folder on the share drive itself just to be sure.
robocopy "Z:\Support\Development" "Z:\SmithJ\Support_Tool_Backup\%mydate%" /LOG+:"Z:\SmithJ\Support_Tool_Backup\log.txt"
```